# Getting tasks from esxi

Tags: c#, vmware, esxi

I have the following code:

```
VMware.Vim.Task task = new VMware.Vim.Task(Client,thisDC.MoRef);
foreach(VMware.Vim.Task eachTask in task)
                {

                    lvLogging.Items.Add(eachTask.DescriptionId);
                }
```

But I'm getting the error:

```
foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'VMware.Vim.Task' because 'VMware.Vim.Task' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'
```

So I did the following:

```
List<VMware.Vim.Task> task = new List<VMware.Vim.Task>();
task = new VMware.Vim.Task(Client,thisDC.MoRef);
```

but now I have the following error:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'VMware.Vim.Task' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<VMware.Vim.Task>'
```

Am I totally lost here?
What I'm trying to do is to get the tasks from a ESXi host and then send to a ListView.

Answer (score 0):

Your first snippet tries to enumerate a single `Task` (not a list of tasks), and therefore fails. Your second snippet tries to assign a single `Task` to a list of `Tasks` and therefore fails.

You are also abusing the `ManagedObjectReference` structure. It should not contain a `Client`. Rather, it should contain a type string (e.g. "Task", "VirtualMachine", etc.) and a value (e.g. "task-123" or "vm-456"). You should read the [relevant section](https://code.vmware.com/doc/preview?id=4205#/doc/PG_Programming_Model.4.4.html) in the vSphere SDK programming guide - this will be the foundation of whatever APIs you try to consume.

I think a basic point that is lost here is that you will generally not *create* a `Task` on your own; rather, the vSphere API will *return* the `Task` to you based on some criteria you specify. One way of obtaining these tasks is through the [TaskHistoryCollector](https://code.vmware.com/apis/196/vsphere#/doc/vim.TaskHistoryCollector.html), as demonstrated for example [here](https://communities.vmware.com/thread/520597). I suggest you start with the sample in that thread which should be easy enough to convert from Java to C#. See that you can get it to work and that you understand what it does, then post another question if needed.

Comment: Thanks @ysk. I will go through your answers and the sample you linked to. I'm sure that I'll have more questions.